# Wordpress import video's

Tags: wordpress, import, youtube, embedded, blogs

Little bit of background, i am recreating a current wordpress.com website in wordpress.org so the owner can make any changes they want. I completed most of the design and was starting to import data from the old site. A lot of blog posts had the following shortcode in it

```
[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQKUQiY2LVA]
```

This doesn't work in wordpress.org though. So my question is, is their a way to make this shortcode actually work and doesnt require to rewrite every blogpost with a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out [this wordpress.com page about youtube embedding](https://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/youtube/).
Seems like you only have to change a little formatting, wordpress.com uses a similar shortcode.
Just open your .sql file in an editor and perform a search and replace.

Comment: In case you already imported all of the data: 1: export the post data to a .sql file. 2: change the shortcode according to the wordpress.com page. 3: empty the post data table. 4: import the changed data to the post data table (before you start with all of this, backup your database)